# firefox fails to render object tag embedded link unless link is inspected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, embedding

I am trying to embed an html5+javascript based genome browser into a project (jbrowse) so I used this code to embed the page in my html

```
<object id="browser_embed" height="900" width="900" type="text/html" data="some_link"></object>
```

chrome renders it fine, but in firefox the embedded page fails to load unless I inspect the element and select the link, and then if i switch to a different tab, the element reloads and voila the page is right there. Googling told me that this has been a known issue with firefox, but no one has been able to come up with a solution till now. It would be helpful if someone can recommend a fix/workaround for this issue.

So the rendered code is too big as well but its of the form

```
<html><body><div></div><div></div><div><div></div></div><div></div><script><script></body></html>
```

nothing fancy, just plain and simple html and some javascript.

I also tried some jquery to implement the same i.e. reload the link, but it seems this doesn't work as well.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var element_browse = $('.browser_embed').length;
    for(i=1; i<element_count; i++)
    {
            var new_url = $('.browser_embed').eq(i).attr('data');
            $('.browser_embed').eq(i).attr('data', new_url);
            $('.browser_embed').eq(i).load(new_url);
    }
});
```

Please note I changed the id attribute to that of Class.

Comment: sorry can't do that, the browser itself is a local installation so that won't be possible.

Comment: Yeah the link contains a lot of pre-styled html on a which are figuratively describing lots of data so that they make some sense together, I would have posted an image but it seems I need 10 rep for that. So I'll post some of the rendered code.